# browser back button crashes website NextJS 13 after router.push hard navigation (app directory)

Tags: next.js, routes, crash, next.js13

I have a button that needs to programatically change routes using the push method of useRouter from next/navigation. On soft navigation using the back button in Chrome works fine, but on hard navigation using the back button makes the site unresponsive, uses 100% cpu, and closing the tab doesn't work. I have to force quit Chrome.

I've completely removed any middleware that may have been affecting navigation. I also found some old github issues from years ago with similar issues, but couldn't find any solutions in them.

Could someone please take a peak at my very simple codebase using the app router? https://github.com/bztravis88/gifgrams
An example of the back button working with router.push is in the AuthToggle component which switches between the signin and signup routes. An example of a router.push that has this issue is a hard navigation from / to /account

This is my first major project using next js, so I may be misusing things, would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: I've got the same issue just by importing the `useRouter` hook on a new page file.
I'm also using the `app` directory, and CPU is on 100%.

Comment: Removed the `async` from the component. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you cannot define a page.js with a client component that is an async function.

Comment: After removing async from all "use client" components. It started working properly again

Comment: I have this issue but i do not have any use client component that are async but when ever i use the back button i get the network tab spammed with RSC calls to the NextJs server, this eventually crashes the app.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, it was because I have a provider at the root of the app, which is 'use client' I was able to fix this by adding a Suspense wrapper around the provider which does fix this partially.